# Split a string on each numeric value if the numeric value does not contain / or %

Tags: regex, vb.net

I have the following string:

```
XXX,XXX abc this is a test, X.X% first one, X,XXX,XXX def one X/X more test, XX,XXX,XXX last test
```

wher X is a digit. I need to split that string onto 3 parts:

I never know anything in advance, except that each part will start with a digit.
I usually use Regex for things like that and I was wondering if anyone could help me with regex expression to split this string

```
XXX,XXX abc this is a test, X.X% first one
X,XXX,XXX def one more X/X test
XX,XXX,XXX last test
```

I have tried using `Regex.Split(str,"(?=\b\d+\b)")`

but it splits one ever single digit, which is not what I want. It gets me:

```
XXX,
XXX abc this is a test, 
X.
X% first one
X,
XXX,
XXX def one more 
X/
X test
XX,
XXX,
XXX last test
```

Comment: Could you supply the 4 strings you want it split into

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/gV8gW7/4

Comment: ste-fu, it is actually 3, not 4  and they are supplied

Comment: Avinash Raqj, your solution worked pretty well on some strings but nit other. For instance this string"XXX,XXX lbs of XX/XX white sand and X,XXX,XXX lbs of XX/XX white sand. air= XX and atp= XXXX" was not split at all

Comment: I'd split the sample on comma and val(each) to get the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this: `\s+(?=\d+(?:,\d+)+|(?:\d+\s+)|(?:\d+$))`

Works perfectly for your cases, see [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hE6pL6/3).

Comment: it splits on XX/XX as well... for example if the string is "XXX,XXX lbs of XX/XX white sand and X,XXX,XXX lbs of XX/XX white sand. air= XX and atp= XXXX" it should not split on XX/XX

Answer (score 0):

No doubt there's a more elegant solution, but here's a working VB console app that does exactly as you say, splitting that input string into the three strings you describe.

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim input As String = "123,456 abc this is a test, 7.8% first one, 9,012,345 def one 6/7 more test, 89,012,345 last test"

    'Split into component strings, with each string starting with a number (no percents or fractions)
    Dim splitStrings As List(Of String) = SplitOnNumbers(input)

    'Write out each; one line per string
    For Each component As String In splitStrings
        Console.WriteLine(component)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function SplitOnNumbers(input As String) As List(Of String)
    Dim splitStrings As New List(Of String)()

    'Pattern to match all digits not preceded by a "/" and not eventually ending in a "/" or "%"
    Const pattern As String = "(?<!\/)(?:\d+[\,,\.]*)+(?!(%|\/|\.|\,|\d)+)"

    'Get the matching numbers...
    Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(input, pattern)
    '...and the text inbetween the matching numbers
    Dim inbetweenText As String() = Regex.Split(input, pattern)

    'Add the first text element that precedes a number, if any.
    If inbetweenText IsNot Nothing AndAlso inbetweenText(0).Length > 0 Then
        splitStrings.Add(inbetweenText(0))
    End If

    'Combine matching numbers with the text after it
    For i As Integer = 0 To matches.Count - 1
        splitStrings.Add(matches(i).Value + inbetweenText(i + 1))
    Next

    Return splitStrings
End Function
End Module
```

The output looks like this:

```
123,456 abc this is a test, 7.8% first one,
9,012,345 def one 6/7 more test,
89,012,345 last test
```

The Regex.Match() will grab the numbers like "123,456", and the Regex.Split() will grab everything in between. I mashed them back together manually.

The Regex isn't pretty, but it breaks down into three main parts:

1. `(?<!\/)` looks behind to ensure the number isn't with a slash. So it excludes the second half of a fraction.
2. `(?:\d+[\,,\.]*)+` matches numbers, with any commas and periods embedded
3. `(?!(%|\/|\.|\,|\d)+)` makes sure the number doesn't eventually end with a "%" or a "/". I had to include other characters too (digits, periods, commas) or else you'd get a match for the "7." in the "7.8%".